# How to Call a Batch File And Make it Run as Administrator

Tags: batch-file

I have a situation where one batch file (BatFile1) calls another batch file (BatFile2).  In order to work properly BatFile2 must Run as Administrator.  (Note: BatFile2 only runs when called by BatFile1.  It is never run manually.)

1. Is there an argument I can put on the Call command line in BatFile1 that will cause BatFile2 to run as an administrator?  Something like:
   Call  c:\BatFile2.bat  /RUN-AS-ADMINISTRATOR
2. Is there some other way to run BatFile2 from BatFile1 (other than the Call command) that will cause BatFile2 to run as administrator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run other batch file as Administrator run:

```
powershell.exe -command "& {Start-Process .\batfile2.bat -ArgumentList "Args" -Verb Runas}"
```

Or if you want You can make the batfile1 auto-elevate itself try:

```
goto="Batch" /*
:Admin
@echo off
REM CONTINUE CODE HERE
exit /b 0
:RunAsAdmin
color 4f & echo Running Admin Shell, Please wait.... & call cscript //nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" RunAsAdmin "%*" & exit /b
:"Batch"
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cls
openfiles >nul 2>&1 || goto :RunAsAdmin
goto :Admin
:"JScript" */
function RunAsAdmin(self, arguments) { WSH.CreateObject('Shell.Application').ShellExecute(self, arguments, '', 'runas', 1) }
if (WSH.Arguments.length>=1 && WSH.Arguments(0)=='RunAsAdmin') RunAsAdmin(WSH.ScriptFullName,WSH.Arguments(1));
//
```

This is a Jscript-Batch hybrid can be saved as .bat file. Continue your code in the Admin label.

Another way using powershell embedded:

```
@echo off
openfiles >nul 2>&1
if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
    color 4f
    echo Running Admin Shell, Please wait.......
    powershell Start-Process -FilePath "%0" -ArgumentList "%*" -verb runas >NUL 2>&1
    exit /b 0
)
::Batch code here
```

After Runas the Current directory maybe changed, so Male sure you change it.

Comment: Make sure to replace "Args" with the arguments of the second batch file and include the full path if needed and if it worked please accept the answer by clicking the big check mark.